# Fill a mat-table's cell with a color

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a fairly basic column in a `mat-table` as follows:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="zone">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header></mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [style.background-color]="'#' + item.zone.color"></mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    ...

</mat-table>
```

I'd like to fill `zone` column cells with some colors varying from row to row (not the whole row, only cells of this specific column).

All I could find so far is coloring the whole row.

The cells of the `zone` column are rendered to the following HTML:

```
<mat-cell class="mat-cell cdk-column-zone mat-column-zone" role="gridcell" style="background-color: rgb(255, 182, 193);" _ngcontent-c8=""></mat-cell>
```

We can see that `background-color` style property has been correctly applied, but the problem is that cell's height is 0. because the cell doesn't have any content. I tried to put an `&nbsp;` inside the cell, but it gets displayed as a thin bar with top and bottom margins:

[image]

And what I want is to color the whole cell including its margins.

How can we color individual cells in `mat-table`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the default CSS provided by [`Angular Material`](https://material.angular.io), you will notice that the `mat-row` element has a minimum height of **48px**.

[image: mat-row height]

But if you look at the `mat-cell` you will notice that it don't have a minimum neither a default height set, it relies on the parent element (the row) display / alignment properties to stay centered.

[image: mat-cell height]

If you look at the previous image it shows exactly the area that is being colored by the background color property in your code.

So for changing the background color for the entire cell, one of your options would be to set the same minimum height used by the rows to the cells, which could be done using the following CSS declaration:

```
.mat-cell, .mat-header-cell {
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 48px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And then simple use the background color property for changing the color.

Comment: Thank you! What if they change minimum height of `mat-row` to `30px` in the next release? Is there a solution more independent from constants in the Material CSSs?

Comment: Simple use the same SCSS variable they used to generate the CSS. You can check it here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/d2f41a4da1faf3c8abcf076676347b5e1e044fb9/src/lib/table/table.scss#L1

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same requirement using dynamic material table. Can u share the code in stackblitZ to know about zones?